# Generate heat on an android phone (from code, of course)

Tags: android

I need to heat up an android phone (don't ask...)

So far I tried running a max priority thread with a while loop which ROL-s an integer around, but that generates too little heat, even though the phone comes down almost to a halt. I tried doing complex math in the loop, but the results were same. I tried with more threads, but as expected it behaves exactly as it was with just one thread.

What can I do to tax it enough in order for it to generate more heat?

**Edit**: Some additional info - It's basically an application that should run as a background service (android Service started with startService()) which uses notifications to indicate that it's running (or not). Ideally, it should have no UI at all, other than the control-activity to start/stop it. I already made the service, notifications and the controlling activity. The Service uses it's own thread for phone heating, so that it would not interfere with activity's UI (which is in the same android app), now I only need to write the "meat" of the thread, i.e. some code that would actually cause the phone to heat up.

Comment: You say "don't ask", but nevertheless I'm pretty darn curious... :-)

Comment: It's a task for a local android programming contest. My friend, who is a designer, had this idea of a phone as a heater, he made concept art and gfx and they loved it. Now I need to implement it but it's harder than it sounds :)

Comment: @Boris B: +1 up & Fav. I've already found some good uses for such application in this coming winter. I'm looking forward to see your application. And i would really like to see your source to see how you did it, if its not a problem of course.

Comment: Even tho I think that it theory it is a nice idea in practice it is no that nice. I'm sure everyone is aware that it is going to drain the battery which is ok if it would be only that but you're also decreasing the parts life time. On top of that right now there is a hype for green technologies converting electric power to hear is not exactly the best project with regards to green technologies. It would be cool to combine that with a solar charging station so basically converting solar energy to electrical energy to heat.

Comment: @Fábio Antunes: I would be happy to share the source (all ~500 lines of it for now :), but I'd have to check the contest organizer's rules, because the organizer is a local mobile operator and it could be that all of the contest's code will become their property.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean: That's why I'm trying to generate the heat off the CPU only, because the battery drain should be the least (as opposed to say WiFi, BT, or GSM)

Comment: @Boris B. Yes your right usually the CPU is the component that uses less energy. But you should also remind that in order to heat the CPU enough to heat up the phone it would take a serious load on the system, probably compromising the normal use of the CPU by other applications.

Comment: @Boris B. I also forgot to mentioned, the CPU is also the component that loses less energy in the form of heat. So more additional load would be necessary to heat up the CPU.

Comment: @Boris B: You might be right with your assumption that the CPU is the less power draining component but thats only given when it is operating normally. If you stress it to its maximum it will also drain more power. It can't convert void into heat the energy has to come from somewhere.

Comment: Not yet, I'm currently 600km away from work, I'll continue next week. I can confirm that showing high-res video does actually heat up the device considerably more than any kind of math calculation I do in a thread:)

Comment: @Boris B. Looking forward to see who you did it.

Comment: The app is up, you can download it at http://www.egosenti.si/grelec/. It needs Android 2.1 at least and you'd have to enable Unknown sources, because eventhough the app is signed it's not from the Marketplace. And if you like it be sure to "Like" it using FB since we need the votes (the contest is still on)  :) If they allow it I will upload the sources after the contest.

Comment: Do you think you can share the code nowadays? I would be interested in warming up my CPU before benchmarking my application, so that I can know what would be its performance when the CPU is under stress...

Comment: In the end I am using this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.into.stability&hl=it

Comment: try some lottie files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically turn on everything you can that uses power, in addition to the CPU:

- Keep the screen on and bright (if you have an OLED fill it with white).  The best way to do this is with an activity setting FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON and maximum brightness.
- Monitor location with GPS.
- Send and receive data over the network.
- Use OpenGL to draw some moving graphics (to run the GPU, and get the surface compositor going).
- Play audio.

Something you can't do in software but is also a big battery drain is being in a low signal area, so the cell radio needs to bump up its power.

Or just run Google Navigation...  it already does nearly all of that, and is indeed and big battery drainer and device warmer. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, will definitely try OpenGL drawing.

Comment: OpenGL is THE way to go. Try to update it with max framerate and draw several white bitmaps with anti aliasing over eachother. Use alpha etc, if you tweak the white to be different but still almost max white, it serves both purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to also write data to SD-Card and phone storage at a high frequency and enable the Wifi and GPS sensors. Also set the screen to the maximal brightness and maybe show some complex graphics or videos on it too.

Comment: Maybe be careful of this, IIRC storage degrades with read/writes.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is to connect it to USB to charge up and run Wifi Tether. That gets the CPU up to about 43 degrees Celsius at least.

Comment: That won't do, it has to be a stand-alone solution, no external USB or anything, and I cannot turn on bluetooth/wifi or do anything that would change the state of the phone behind the user's back.

Answer (score 1):

My droid gets awfully warm while using Google Navigator.  It tends to warm up while gaming and browsing the internet too but Google Nav makes it heat up the most.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for nearby bluetooth devices over and over is not recommended since it will drain the battery. This might generate some heat too.

Comment: This heat _must_ come from the battery! That is the source of energy. The important thing is that it is converted into heat and not light / radio waves.

Answer (score 0):

I find playing high quality video gets my Nexus One blazing in no time at all.

Answer (score 0):

I always get cold feet when I'm skiing in Colorado. Would love a copy of your handywork!

And to add a suggestion, in case the video playback suggestion does not generate enough heat, try video conversion with crop and resize...  I had one of those ugly overpriced Alienware gaming laptop clunkers that would play back video without getting hot, but upon running a video conversion (reducing a DVD to 600x300 rez with 4 sided crop for my phone) using Handbreak, it overheated so bad, it died with a puff of smoke. When I turn it on now, the screen simply flashes back and white.

Answer (score 0):

Once i was fixing the game which heating app devices. There were a lot of frequent writing/reading `SharedPreferences`. Before every round(~4sec) it read scores from `SharedPreferences` and after it wrote scores. It crazy heats up the phone.

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents regarding efficiency, which in this case is how much of the battery energy is transformed in heat. The maximum efficiency is obtained when all energy is converted in heat *inside* the phone. So, looking from another perspective, all energy *emitted* (in any other form than heat) is wasted.

For example, using wireless (in any form) would imply transmitting some energy in the environment in the form of electromagnetic waves, which wouldn't transform in energy inside the phone and therefore be wasted for the purpose of this application. "Flight mode" would avoid wasting energy in this respect.

The same might be said for keeping the display on: battery energy would be converted in light and it would exit from the phone.

Therefore using at maximum CPU and GPU (although keeping the display off :) ) seems to be the way to obtain the maximum efficiency for an application thought for warming up the phone. Also monitoring position through GPS antenna should be fine (passive reception). Playing audio might be a good idea, as long as energy is not wasted by generating sound waves. Somebody suggested writing on the internal storage and SD card, also a good idea (but might ware off the SD card).